# Set keyboard shortcuts for accessing specific render slots?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, customization, shortcut

I want to press '1' to go to 1st Render Slot, '2' to go to the 2nd, and so on.
[image: render slots]

I did this before but my keyboard shortcut file got corrupted. I don't recall how I had set it up in the past.

I'm looking at the Image Generic shortcuts and see no such listings. I am clueless as to what shortcut code to type in. Help?

[image: image generic shortcut]

Comment: Strange, I KNOW I've done this before, but it doesn't appear in the Image Operators API. Maybe it's undocumented?

https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78_release/bpy.ops.image.html

Comment: That is the default behavior, no need to reinvent the wheel

Comment: Hmm, it does not happen in my file. Perhaps it got corrupted too.. Would you mind sharing the API shortcut code?

Answer (score 2):

Found it. 
API to enter for the shortcut is:
**wm.context_set_int**
Make sure Value is set to the slot number minus 1. 
Context Attributes must be: space_data.image.render_slots.active_index

That's how you get the render slot numpad shortcuts back, if they disappeared like mine did and you don't want to reset everything.

[image: Keyboard Shortcut Solution]

Comment: I took the liberty to correct your arithmetics. 1 minus the slot would yield negative numbers for slot numbers >= 2.

Comment: This is not default behaviour. By default Numpad 1 and Numpad 2 are Zoom 1:1 and 1:2 respectively, so maybe you reset your custom shortcuts somehow.